# What are verbs specific to living subjects called?

Tags: verbs, subjects

The set of verbs applicable to living organisms can also apply to other inanimate subjects like rain forests (e.g. `resembled`, `looked`) but I'd like to identify those verbs which are **strictly** applicable to living organisms.

Perhaps this is a better representation:

[image]

While it's possible for a forest to speak figuratively, I only want to focus on the literal use of these verbs. I want to identify the organism verbs, including human verbs. Oh, and deceased subjects that were once living should also be considered as organisms.

Comment: what about animals?

Comment: I don't think there are any. Any verb a human can do, a monkey, a robot, or a God can do.

Comment: That's true, I can count "Lenny the monkey ate..." as a valid use of this kind of verb. I'm trying to identify between the names of people/pets and those of places/things.

Comment: I updated my question to distinguish a bit better

Comment: You still have to distinguish between animate, volitional, and human. Not to mention physical from metaphorical. And active from stative, emotional from mental, and non-subject constructions like _frightens me_, _not to my taste_, or _gives me goosebumps._

Comment: Try [linguistics.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe such a distinction can be drawn; anything can be personified to use any verb, at least metaphorically.

The sun can smile upon a child's summer day. Necessity can mother invention. Trees converse whenever the wind blows. The old mountain can swallow the inexperienced.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point and mentioned I was only considering literal uses of these verbs, but I doubt there such a concept from the comments above. Thanks alot, I guess I'll compile a list or something.